# .NET MAUI App sometimes when coming from foreground goes to first page

Tags: .net, maui

Need some help to solve something that i can't figure it out what could be. The APP doesn't crash but if it is on foreground for sometime, sometimes days, it can come from foreground with the splash screen and ends up on the start. I don't quite know if i need to create a background service to keep running while in foreground so that doesn't happen. If anyone have that kind of experience using a .NET MAUI please some help. It can be memoryleak? And the OS needs to restart the APP? but that way wouldn't crash instead? Something that i can do on the APP cycle management?

Comment: the OS will shut down the app if it decides that it needs to free system resources.  There is not much you can do about this.  You can store the state of your app when it is shutdown and then use this to restore the user to the prior state.  Many browser apps do this.

Comment: when saying restore state i can save where the user was and give back that location. But still when it comes this way on a restart it shows the splash screen

Comment: yes, you can't prevent the OS from displaying your splash screen

Comment: well i see  now, i am glad that i could understand this, thanks for sharing this knowledge @Jason,